# Nutch web spider, index entire web

Tags: regex, nutch

Alright, I've been messing around with [Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/) and need to know what parameter inside the `crawl-urlfilter.txt` file I edit so the spider has **no boundaries**. In other words I want it to roam around the web outside of a specified domain.

I'm assuming it has to do with this line, but I don't know how to edit it correctly to do as I want it to:

```
+^http://([a-z0-9]*\.)*urlz.net/
```

Comment: It seems to be matching with urls under domain `urlz.net`. Try to use `+^http://([a-z0-9]*\.)*` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not framiliar with Nutch but this is just a regular expression.

```
+^http://([a-z0-9\.])*
```

Would probably work just fine, or some variation thereof. Its just matching a pattern. The one I just wrote above should match anything starting with http:// and then any number of letters, numbers or dots.

Comment: It should, I fixed it after reading Oscar's post, so the one in the answer should be good to go.